# SwiftUI NavigationView size to fit content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a bottom sheet that contains a NavigationView to support back and forth transitions managed by a coordinator.

As far as I saw, the NavigationView automatically uses all the space it can - independent of whether its content actually needs this space. I can limit it by using paddings/spacers or a frame modifier, but I want the NavigationView to resize itself based on the content I put in there (dynamically, cause the content may change at runtime).

Does someone know how to achieve that?

[With default Spacer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhISh.png) :(

[With Spacer that has minLength = 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhElT.png) :)
That's what it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unusual use of NavigationView, actually there might be coming other issues along the way.
I couldn't get if to work with flexible size by GeometryReader, but for fixed you can do this:

```
    VStack {
        Color.clear // takes all available space above
        NavBottomSheet() // your Nav View
            .frame(maxHeight: 200) // you have to give it a fixed size
    }
```

Comment: Yeah with a fixed size it's no problem. I could actually get it to work with a GeometryReader that updates my size PreferenceKey based on it's value. But I thought there must be a native/straight-forward way to achieve this. Cause I don't want to use such a workaround.